# What is the meaning of "arc-en-ciel" in the phrase "manger un parfait arc-en-ciel"?

Tags: sens, alimentation

I just heard this colloquial sentence on YouTube:

> Mais je suis sûr que je peux lui rendre le sourire si je l’emmène **manger** **un parfait arc-en-ciel**, t'en fais pas !

You cannot eat a "*rainbow*" to begin with. The possibility of "*poisson* arc-en-ciel" occurred to me, too, but there is no particular mention of any fish, either.

Then I wonder... Could it be about eating various fruits and vegetables of different colours as diverse as those of a rainbow?

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with this pastry, but I wonder if this person did not mean *un parfait* (noun, not adjective), which is a certain kind of cake. But I have no idea how it could be *arc-en-ciel*... Maybe there is a variant where the *parfait* is made with various fruits, as you suggest ? I only know the *parfaits* made with vanilla or chocolate...

Comment: [Rainbow parfaits](https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/rainbow-parfait-624x415.jpg)

Comment: Some context would probably help this sentence is pretty confusing.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Probably, that's it! Do you often see something like the one in the photo in Canada? Every time I visit Canada, I'm flabbergasted (from a Japanese perspective) by how extraordinarily colourful the sweets are in general. ;)

Comment: @Greg Probably the one in Luke's comment. :) By the way, when you say "*si je l’**emmène manger** ...*", who is (grammatically speaking) supposed to "manger": "je" or "elle"? Given the context, it is "elle", but...

Comment: It would be "elle". You could perfectly say *Je l'emmène manger. Mais moi je ne mangerai rien, j'ai déjà mangé*.

Comment: @Alone-zee I haven't yet seen a rainbow parfait in person, but I do see rainbow other things, such as [this cake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hQvv.jpg) that I took a photo of just today.

Comment: @LukeSawczak 770 cals... (haha) We'd be hard pressed to find that type of colourful sweets in Japan! No wonder the phrase "manger un parfait arc-en-ciel" didn't make sense to me. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the comment thread, it seems safe to offer this reparsing, owed entirely to Greg:

> un parfait « arc-en-ciel » → **un parfait couleur arc-en-ciel**

There are various dishes called a « parfait », but the [dessert glacé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parfait_(dessert)) (also see more detailed [English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parfait)) seems like the most likely one.

Searching for « parfait arc-en-ciel » suggests that the rainbow could be achieved either by dye or by using something like your fruit hypothesis to constitute the « parfum » of the parfait.

[image: Dye]

[image: Fruit]

Comment: Hi, Luke. I'm curious -- Does Starbucks in Canada offer sweets and drinks with glaring colours like these? :D